# Project with path could not be found in root project Android Studio

Tags: android

Actually few hours ago my project has no error, but I don't know what changes happened from me unknowingly and now I'm getting following error-- 
"***Error:(36, 0) Project with path ':easyAndroidAnimationsLibrary' could not be found in root project 'wikiReviews'***". I googled and checked for my project hierarchy, gradle file, setting file everything seems to be OK but unable to trace the real problem yet. Please see the following image to check hierarchy--

[image]

My build.gradle is--

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.myleomo.wikiReviews"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':easyAndroidAnimationsLibrary')
        compile project(':liveSdk')
        compile project(':main')
        compile project(':zbarSample')
        compile project(':stickyHeaderLibrary')
        compile project(':starBar')
        compile project(':facebookSDK')
        compile project(':library')
        compile project(':ffmpeg4android_lib')
        compile project(':socialNetworkingLib')    
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
        compile files('libs/nmdp_speech_kit.jar')
        compile files('libs/AndroidSwipeLayout-v1.1.8.jar')   
        compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
        compile files('libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar')
        compile files('libs/devsmartandroid.jar')   
        compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.6.0-beta'

        compile files('libs/google-api-services--v1-1.3.0-beta.jar')   
        compile files('libs/httpclient-4.4.jar')    
        compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-commonshttp4', version: '1.2'

        compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-core', version: '1.2.1.2'

        compile group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-jetty6', version: '1.2.1.1'

        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

      '4.4-alpha1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'


    version: '4.3.5.1'
        compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3')
                {
                    exclude module: "httpclient"
                }
    }
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Below is my top level build. gradle--

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Below is my settings.gradle--

```
include ':easyAndroidAnimationsLibrary'
include ':facebookSDK'
include ':liveSdk'
include ':socialNetworkingLib'
include ':starBar'
include ':stickyHeaderLibrary'
include ':zbarSample'
include ':ffmpeg4android_lib'
include ':library'
include ':main'
include ':wikiReviews'
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information for the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your project should be wikiReviews. 
I guess the way of your project loaded from android studio maybe wrong